# How to calculate the offset distance of triangle

Tags: trigonometry

I need to find the offset distance of 2 points.

I start with my basic shape

The dashed lines are help lines

[image: base shape]

Now I will offset the line and need to find point X and Y

[image: offset]

Since I only know the offset and nothing else I wonder how to continue from here

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general figure, where the given data are angle $a$ and width $w$.

[image]

with $a+2b=90° \ \iff \ a=90°-2b \ \iff \ b=\frac12(90°-a).$

What you need is the value of the vertical displacement $BC$.

As we have

$$\dfrac{BC}{w}=\tan b$$

we deduce that :

$$BC=w \tan b = w \tan(\frac12(90°-a))$$

The numerical application gives:

$$BC=3.5 \tan(33.61 \underbrace{\pi/180}_{*})\approx 2.32715$$

where (*) accounts for the conversion degrees $\to$ radians, which coincide with your calculation.

Comment: Our results coincide ; at first I didn't find exactly the same thing as you because I had interpreted your measures as being in degrees and minutes, whereas you use decimal degrees.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have something like this and the vertical distances are easy to find

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gskXb.png)

Comment: Point x is 2,3262 lower the the point it was offset off.